# Was ist die korrekte Abkürzung für Zweidrittelmehrheit?

Tags: abbreviation

2/3-Mehrheit oder 2/3 Mehrheit oder 2/3-mehrheit? Oder gar nicht?

Comment: Am besten gar nicht. Deine Abkürzungen sehen gruslig aus. Und nur eine davon ist richtig (§40 der Rechtschreibregeln)

Comment: Es heisst kürzer "absolute Mehrheit "

Comment: @Beta Es gibt aber einen [Unterschied](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mehrheit) zwischen absoluter und Zweidrittelmehrheit.

Comment: @Beta: Die absolute Mehrheit hat man schon, wenn man mehr als 50% aller gültigen Stimmen erreicht. Als Synonym für die Zweidrittelmehrheit kenne ich nur den Begriff *Verfassungsmehrheit* (zumindest in Österreich), weil das die Grenze ist, um Verfassungsgesetze zu ändern.

Comment: Da habt ihr natürlich recht @HubertSchölnast und IQV. Den Begriff ich schreiben hat wollen, war eigentlich "Qualifizierte mehrheit", habe aber die Begriffe vermischt. https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mehrheit#Qualifizierte_Mehrheit

Comment: Welche Mehrheit als absolut oder qualifiziert gilt, ist eine Frage von Gesetzen, Vorschriften und Satzungen - hat nichts mit der sprachlichen Frage zu tun. Der Begriff Zweidrittelmehrheit ist absolut legitim und gebräuchlich.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Die amtliche Regelung zu [Bindestrichen](http://canoonet.eu/services/GermanSpelling/Amtlich/Bindestrich/pgf40-45.html) besagt in § 40, dass man "**einen Bindestrich in Zusammensetzungen mit Einzelbuchstaben, Abkürzungen oder Ziffern**" schreibt.

Der genannte Begriff wird hierbei sogar in den Beispielen genannt:

> 2/3‑Mehrheit

Die anderen Vorschläge zu den Abkürzungen sind daher nicht richtig.

Ob aber jemand die Abkürzung oder die ausgeschriebene Variante besser gefällt, ist meiner Ansicht nach Sache des persönlichen Geschmacks und wäre damit off-topic.