# Kombination von Zahl und Abkürzung

Tags: spelling, compound, abbreviation, numbers, hyphen

Die sog. „westliche Musik“ basiert auf einer sogenannten [Gleichstufige Stimmung](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gleichstufige_Stimmung), diese teilt das fundamentale Intervall Oktave (zwei Töne, deren Grundschwingung das Frequenzverhältnis 2:1 aufweisen, wodurch eine sehr starke klangliche Übereinstimmung wahrgenommen wird) in zwölf gleichgroße Teile.

Nun gibt es weitere Möglichkeiten, die Oktave in gleichgroße Teile zu gliedern, z.B. die Musik anderer Kulturkreise adäquat zu beschreiben (5-Teilungen in Gamelan, 7-Teilungen in Georgischer Polyphony). Zur Erleichterung haben sich für all diese Systeme - vor allem im englischsprachigen Raum - die Abkürzungen ET (''Equal Temperament'') und EDO (''Equal Division of the Octave'') etabliert. Werden solche Systeme konkretisiert, indem die Anzahl der Teile genannt wird, dann finden wir Schreibungen wie 12-ET oder 12-EDO bzw. 12 EDO.

Da die Mehrzahl der Veröffentlichungen zu dieser Thematik bislang in Englischer Sprache  vorliegt, wird die dort gefestigte Nomenklatur auch im deutschen Sprachraum genutzt. Nun meine Frage zur Schreibung im Deutschen, leider enthalten die Regeln und Beispiele, die ich bislang gefunden habe, nichts zu genau diesem Muster: *Zahl am Beginn, gefolgt von einer Abkürzung*. Gefunden habe ich aber z.B. 257-Eck oder 3/4-Takt.

- [Viertelgeviertstrich: Bindestrich – Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viertelgeviertstrich#Bindestrich)
- [Schreibweise von Zahlen: Zahl-Wort-Kombinationen – Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schreibweise_von_Zahlen#Zahl-Wort-Kombinationen)
- [Rechtschreibung von Zahlen im Deutschen: Verbindungen zwischen Buchstaben und Ziffern](https://www.unker.com/de/rechtschreibung-zahlen#verbindungen)

Ich würde aus dem Bauch heraus dazu tendieren, *12-EDO* zu schreiben, da *12 EDO* auf mich wie die Kombination von Zahl und Einheit wirkt (ich habe aber auch schon *12EDO* gelesen). Dabei könnte ich es belassen, aber da ich diese Entscheidung für eine Veröffentlichung benötige, von der eine gewisse Normungswirkung ausgehen könnte, wäre mir mit einer fundierten Vorab-Auskunft sehr gedient.

Comment: nur ne Meinung: bei "12 EDO" würde ich EDO auch als Maßeinheit verstehen, "12-EDO" wäre für mich eine Bezeichnung. Okay. länger nachgedacht, würde ich glatt ein "Duplikat" in den Raum rufen: https://german.stackexchange.com/q/39854/36160

Comment: @ShegitBrahm Danke für das Feedback! Selbst wenn wir keine hieb- und stichfesten Regeln finden, helfen mir auch Meinungsäußerungen, ein Gespür für Verständlichkeit und Lesbarkeit auf der Seite potentieller Leser zu entwickeln.

Comment: Das ist doch in §40 und folgenden [Rechtschreibregeln](https://www.korrekturen.de/regelwerk/pdf/Regeln_2018.pdf) definiert oder? Alles andere ist leider "opinion based"..

Comment: @choXer Danke für die Referenz! Du meinst also *§40 insbes. (C) Zusammensetzungen mit Ziffern [...]*? Ich finde das sehr knapp gehalten und Abkürzungen kommen hinter Zahl+Bindestrich nicht vor, aber anscheinend im Hauptsatz der Regel (*Man setzt einen Bindestrich in Zusammensetzungen mit Einzelbuch-staben, Abkürzungen oder Ziffern.*) erfasst. Anscheinend braucht man nicht nur für Gesetzestexte einen Anwalt. Nun habe ich immerhin das Gefühl, dass ich mit meinen Gefühl nicht völlig daneben liege. Es wäre aber wohl besser, eine echte Antwort zu haben, um auch die letzten Zweifel auszuräumen.

Comment: @ShegitBrahm Was das Duplikat betrifft, ist das so eine Sache. Wegen *12-Teilung der Oktave* hätte ich sicherlich nicht gefragt. Ich finde, dass die Zahl vor der Abkürzung in o.g. Fall erst durch das EDO-Konzept überhaupt eine Bedeutung erhält. Aber vielleicht vermische ich mal wieder zu sehr die semantische mit der sprachlichen Ebene...

Comment: Die Natur- und Ingenieurswissenschaften haben das SI für Einheiten. Wenn es sich um eine Publikation dreht würde ich beim Herausgeber/Editor nachfragen wie sie das dort halten und jedenfalls vor Verwendung technischer Termini genau definieren was man wie meint. Sonst besteht die Gefahr der divergierenden Meinungen :-)

Comment: @choXer's Kommentar enthält die Rechtschreibregeln dazu, nach denen, so wie ich sie lese, ein Bindestrich passsend wäre, und wenn der mit internationalen Gepflogenheiten zusammenpasst, klingt das ja nach einer guten Lösung. Über diese Rechtschreibregeln hinaus finde ich die Frage auch eher meinungslastig, was ja hier auf SE nicht so gewünscht ist.

Comment: @a_donda Im genannten Fall bin ich Teil des Gremiums ;) und mit der Zeit hat sich auf Grund des geringen Interesses an Standardisierung ein Wildwuchs an Schreibungen entwickelt, den ich gern mit einer Regelung beenden möchte, die sich möglichst harmonisch in ein größeres Ganzes einpasst.

Comment: @HalvarF wenn das hier alle so sehen, dann ist es wohl so, dass meine Frage mit der nach der 2/3-Mehrheit unter ein Dach gehört. Die Wortmeldungen helfen mir auf jeden Fall beim Einordnen des Regeltextes. Und da dieser meinen Neigungen entspricht, sollte  ich es wohl dabei bewenden lassen.